# How do I open my backend NodeJS app for HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, aws-networking

I would like to open backend NodeJS app for the HTTPS traffic as well. I created the key.pem and cert.pem file (self assigned) inside the backend/secrets app with the command:

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Then changed the *main.ts* file as below:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ConfigService } from './modules/config/config.service';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from './modules/app/app.module';
import { AppLogger } from './modules/app/app.logger';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import { TransformInterceptor } from './modules/common/interceptors/TransformInterceptor';
import * as express from 'express';
import { ErrorFilter } from './modules/errors/error.filter';
import * as https from 'https'; //ES 6
import fs from 'fs';
async function bootstrap() {
  const logger = new AppLogger();
  logger.info(`NodeJs Version ${process.version}`);
  logger.info(JSON.stringify(process.env));
  const server = express();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server), {
    logger,
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true }));
  const apiVersionPrefix: string = process.env.API_VERSION || 'api';
  app.setGlobalPrefix(apiVersionPrefix);
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor());
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Glee2')
    .setDescription('Glee2 API')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('customTag')
    .setBasePath(apiVersionPrefix)
    .addBearerAuth() // here is an intentional compile error. Remove the "x" and the backend should compile.
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup(`api/${apiVersionPrefix}`, app, document);
  const config: ConfigService = app.get('ConfigService');
  const whitelist = config.CORS_WHITELIST;
  const corsOptions = {
    origin(origin, callback) {
      const isOriginAllowed = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
      const allowAccessAnyway = whitelist.length === 0;
      if (isOriginAllowed || allowAccessAnyway) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
  };
  const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/cert.pem'),
  };
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  app.useGlobalFilters(new ErrorFilter());
  await app.listen(config.PORT);
  await https.createServer(httpsOptions, server).listen(443);
  logger.log(`Listening on port ${config.PORT}.`);
}
bootstrap();
```

In the AWS EC2 instance, open the port for 443. Port 3030 for the HTTP is working well and return the response:

```
$ curl -s http://34.201.57.229:3030/api/status
```

However, the query with the HTTPS is not working and doesn't return anything.

```
$ curl -s https://34.201.57.229:443/api/status

$ curl -v https://34.201.57.229:443/api/status

*   Trying 34.201.57.229...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 34.201.57.229 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 34.201.57.229 port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 34.201.57.229 port 443: Connection refused
```

The issue is port 443 is open for all traffic

[image]

How do I make the backend working with HTTPS?

Comment: Could you try `curl -v https://34.201.57.229:443/api/status` and paste the result

Comment: The data is provided in the original question.

Comment: I have a concern if this really is the best approach to achieve HTTPS for an EC2 service. I'm not an expert in AWS but have you considered offloading that responsibility to "outside" of your application? Seems like a better architecture to me if the service itself does not have to handle SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ConfigService } from './modules/config/config.service';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from './modules/app/app.module';
import { AppLogger } from './modules/app/app.logger';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import { TransformInterceptor } from './modules/common/interceptors/TransformInterceptor';
import * as express from 'express';
import { ErrorFilter } from './modules/errors/error.filter';
import * as https from 'https'; //ES 6
// modified here
import * as http from 'http'; //ES 6
import fs from 'fs';
async function bootstrap() {
  const logger = new AppLogger();
  logger.info(`NodeJs Version ${process.version}`);
  logger.info(JSON.stringify(process.env));
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server), {
    logger,
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true }));
  const apiVersionPrefix: string = process.env.API_VERSION || 'api';
  app.setGlobalPrefix(apiVersionPrefix);
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor());
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Glee2')
    .setDescription('Glee2 API')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('customTag')
    .setBasePath(apiVersionPrefix)
    .addBearerAuth() // here is an intentional compile error. Remove the "x" and the backend should compile.
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup(`api/${apiVersionPrefix}`, app, document);
  const config: ConfigService = app.get('ConfigService');
  const whitelist = config.CORS_WHITELIST;
  const corsOptions = {
    origin(origin, callback) {
      const isOriginAllowed = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
      const allowAccessAnyway = whitelist.length === 0;
      if (isOriginAllowed || allowAccessAnyway) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
  };
  const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/cert.pem'),
  };
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  app.useGlobalFilters(new ErrorFilter());

  // modified here
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);

  httpServer.listen(config.PORT);
  httpsServer.listen(443);
  // modified end

  logger.log(`Listening on port ${config.PORT}.`);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Can you tell me what changes you make? Otherwise, I dont find it comfortable to copy/ paste it.

Comment: i have added some comments

Comment: The code doesnt work :{

Comment: same error as before?

Comment: Yes the same errro as before

Comment: did your program output any error message ?